# Need to add an array into another array at a specified key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok, I have an array like so, but it's not guaranteed to be laid out in this order all of the time...

```
$array = array(
    'sadness' => array(
        'info' => 'some info',
        'info2' => 'more info',
        'value' => 'value',
    ),
    'happiness' => array(
        'info' => 'some info',
        'info2' => 'more info',
        'value' => 'the value',
    ),
    'peace' => array(
        'info' => 'some info',
        'info2' => 'more info',
        'value' => 'the value',
    )
);
```

Ok, and I'd like to throw in this array right after the happiness key is defined.  I can't use the key of "peace" since it must go directly after happiness, and peace might not come after happiness as this array changes.

So here's what I need to add after happiness...

```
$another_array['love'] = array(
    'info' => 'some info',
    'info2' => 'more info',
    'value' => 'the value of love'
);
```

So the final output after it gets inputted directly after happiness should look like this:

```
$array = array(
    'sadness' => array(
        'info' => 'some info',
        'info2' => 'more info',
        'value' => 'value',
    ),
    'happiness' => array(
        'info' => 'some info',
        'info2' => 'more info',
        'value' => 'the value',
    ),
    'love' => array(
        'info' => 'some info',
        'info2' => 'more info',
        'value' => 'the value of love',
    ),
    'peace' => array(
        'info' => 'some info',
        'info2' => 'more info',
        'value' => 'the value',
    )
);
```

Can someone please give me a hand with this.  Using array_shift, array_pop, or array_merge doesn't help me at all, since these go at the beginning and at the end of the array.  I need to place it directly after a KEY position within $array.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to have an array with two identical keys `'love'`. This is not possible.

EDIT:

You can do:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $new_array[$k] = $v;
        if($k == 'happiness') {
                $new_array['love'] = $another_array['love'];
        }
}
```

[**working example**](http://www.ideone.com/3wJ2Z)

Comment: I just noticed this and fixed it.  Thank You, but the question remains.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me that you didn't understand that in PHP all arrays are hashes (associative arrays). So the order can't be influenced. If you need to have a particular order you need to use sort etc. to define a particular order or use a simple array

```
$order = array ('love', 'happiness', 'pease');
```

Use the $order array to access $array. In the $order array the keys are 1, 2, 3...

Comment: So wait, you are saying that you can't use a foreach to append the $another_array into the $array?  I mean, couldn't you use the key() function somehow and current() and perhaps next() php functions???

Comment: Or even build an entirely different array and than set $array to that other built array??

Comment: You can use foreach etc. but you can't define the order of the entries within the array...the only possible solution is to create a separate array (like i mentioned) to define the order and using the entries in the order array to access the $array...